# Python subprocess call throws error when writing file

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, text-to-speech

I'd like to use SVOX/pico2wave to write a wav-file from Python code. When I execute this line from a terminal the file is written just fine:

```
/usr/bin/pico2wave -w=/tmp/tmp_say.wav "Hello world."
```

I've verified that pico2wave is located in `/usr/bin`.

This is my Python code:

```
from subprocess import call

call('/usr/bin/pico2wave -w=/tmp/tmp_say.wav "Hello world."')
```

... which throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/app.py", line 63, in <module>
    call('/usr/bin/pico2wave -w=/tmp/tmp_say.wav "Hello world."')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 168, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

> Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows
>   the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of
>   arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file names). If passing a single
>   string, either shell must be True (see below) or else the string must
>   simply name the program to be executed without specifying any
>   arguments.

So you might try with

```
call(['/usr/bin/pico2wave', '-w=/tmp/tmp_say.wav', '"Hello world."'])
```

Answer (score 1):

`pico2wave` is fond of throwing this error when used on text which is longer than 4000 words or grammatically faulty.

You can use the code below to efficiently convert any length of text into audio with `pico2wave`; the script splits the input text into segments of maximum length 3500 words, then converts each segment into audio, and finally the segments are concatenated into the final `audio.mp3` file.

(You should follow up the requirements of the
`pyrubberband` lib especially if you want to tune tune the output by stretching, pitch-shifting, etc.)

```
import os
import subprocess
from pydub import AudioSegment
import soundfile as sf
import pyrubberband as pyrb
import subprocess
# Not the requirements of pyrb (sudo apt install libttspico-utils sox)
# pip install numpy Audiosegment pysox sox sndfile

def process_text_segment(text_segment, output_folder, segment_index):
    # Use pico2wave for audio generation
    wav_output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f"audio{segment_index}.wav")
    wav_output_path1 = os.path.join(output_folder, f"audio{segment_index}.wav")
    subprocess.run(['pico2wave', '-w', wav_output_path, '-l', 'en-GB', text_segment])

    # Use pydub for audio processing
    audio = AudioSegment.from_wav(wav_output_path)
    duration = audio.duration_seconds

    # Additional processing steps if needed
    y, sr = sf.read(wav_output_path)
    # Play back at extra low speed
    y_stretch = pyrb.time_stretch(y, sr, 0.73)
    sf.write(wav_output_path1, y_stretch, sr, format='wav')
    # Play back extra low tones
    y, sr = sf.read(wav_output_path1)
    y_shift = pyrb.pitch_shift(y, sr, 1.5)
    sf.write(wav_output_path1, y_shift, sr, format='wav')
    sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(wav_output_path1)
    sound = sound + 12

    # Convert the processed audio to MP3
    mp3_output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f"audio{segment_index}.mp3")
    sound.export(mp3_output_path, format="mp3")

    # Clean up temporary WAV files
    os.remove(wav_output_path)
    os.remove(wav_output_path1)

    return mp3_output_path

def concatenate_audio_segments(output_folder, segment_count, mp3_output_path):
    # Concatenate audio segments
    segments = [AudioSegment.from_mp3(os.path.join(output_folder, f"audio{i}.mp3")) for i in range(1, segment_count + 1)]
    final_audio = sum(segments)

    # Export the final concatenated audio to MP3
    final_audio.export(mp3_output_path, format="mp3")

    # Clean up intermediate audio segments
for i in range(1, segment_count + 1):
        os.remove(os.path.join(output_folder, f"audio{i}.mp3"))

def process_large_text(input_file_path, output_folder):
    with open(input_file_path, "r") as file:
        text_content = file.read()

    # Split text content into segments of maximum 3500 words
    word_limit = 3500
    text_segments = [text_content[i:i+word_limit] for i in range(0, len(text_content), word_limit)]

    segment_count = len(text_segments)

    for i, text_segment in enumerate(text_segments, start=1):
        process_text_segment(text_segment, output_folder, i)

    # Concatenate audio segments
    mp3_output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, "audio.mp3")
    concatenate_audio_segments(output_folder, segment_count, mp3_output_path)

    print(f"Audio generated and saved to {mp3_output_path}")

# Example usage:
input_file_path = "path/to/your/input/file.txt"
output_folder = "path/to/your/output/folder"
process_large_text(input_file_path, output_folder)
```